# Name not unique on network error while adding virtual interface

Tags: ifconfig, wifi, hostapd, iwconfig, networkmanager

I am trying to add an virtual interface type AP for my TP-Link TL-WN722N on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Below is the command I used

```
vinay245@vinay245:~$sudo iw dev wlx60e327078eed interface add wlan0_ap  type __ap
```

There are no issues which creating this I think, however when try to bring up the interface, I get below error

```
vinay245@vinay245:~$ sudo ifconfig rename4 up;
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Name not unique on network
vinay245@vinay245:~$`
```

I am not sure how to resolve this. I have below additional for quick reference

```
vinay245@vinay245:~$ iw dev
phy#0
Interface rename4
  ifindex 4
  wdev 0x2
  addr 60:e3:27:07:8e:ed
  type managed
Interface wlx60e327078eed
  ifindex 3
  wdev 0x1
  addr 60:e3:27:07:8e:ed
  type managed
  channel 1 (2412 MHz), width: 20 MHz, center1: 2412 MHz

vinay245@vinay245:~$ dmesg w | grep htc
[  817.801023] usb 2-1.6: ath9k_htc: Firmware ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw requested
[  817.801129] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath9k_htc
[  818.100582] usb 2-1.6: ath9k_htc: Transferred FW: ath9k_htc/htc_9271-1.4.0.fw, size: 51008
[  818.352940] ath9k_htc 2-1.6:1.0: ath9k_htc: HTC initialized with 33 credits
[  818.616818] ath9k_htc 2-1.6:1.0: ath9k_htc: FW Version: 1.4
[  818.616825] ath9k_htc 2-1.6:1.0: FW RMW support: On
[  818.643293] ath9k_htc 2-1.6:1.0 wlx60e327078eed: renamed from wlan0
[  851.129611] ath9k_htc 2-1.6:1.0 rename4: renamed from wlan0_ap
```

Comment: Also type `__ap` has been changed to `managed` in the iw dev command.

Comment: Kindly try the solution given in [this](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-wireless/msg44139.html) link: > You need to change the mac address of one of the wireless interfaces